# How can i add mouse double click to data grid items wpf

Tags: wpf

In windows form application our data grid view has lots of event like row mouse double click or row click and extra ...

But in WPF i cant find these event .
How can i add row mouse double click to my user control that has a data grid in it

i did it with some bad way that i used **data grid mouse double click event** and some bug happened in this way **but i want know simple and standard way**

i also add double click event to data grid items in **row_load** event but it seems make my program slow if data grid has big source

```
private void dataGrid1_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_MouseDoubleClick);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can handle the double-click on the DataGrid element, then look at the event source to find the row and column that was clicked:

```
private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

    // iteratively traverse the visual tree
    while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
    {
        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
    }

    if (dep == null)
        return;

    if (dep is DataGridColumnHeader)
    {
        DataGridColumnHeader columnHeader = dep as DataGridColumnHeader;
        // do something
    }

    if (dep is DataGridCell)
    {
        DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
        // do something
    }
}
```

I describe this in detail in [this blog post that I wrote](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2008/12/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row/).

Answer (score 0):

The Colin answer was really good and worked ... i also use this code and this was helpfull for me and want to share it to other.

```
private void myGridView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

            // iteratively traverse the visual tree
            while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
            {
                dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
            }

            if (dep == null)
                return;

            if (dep is DataGridRow)
            {
                DataGridRow row = dep as DataGridRow;
               //here i can cast the row to that class i want 
            }
        }
```

As i want know when all row clicked i used this